# setting width of select box of asp dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have gone through similar questions (answers) asked before. They do not have what I need. I need the width of my drop down to be constant all the time. Even when it drops down & items are wider than its width. The wider items should be displayed as a tooltip. How do you do this? And what is the deal with the select element? Why does every post have answers in terms of "select". I am using an asp dropdown. How do I use select with it? Anyway, here's my CSS for the ddl:

```
.ddl2
{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
border-color: Gray;
height: 20px;
max-width: 150px;
}
```

This works (only in firefox) when nothing is selected. As soon as the ddl drops, the selectbox takes the width of the widest element.

EDIT:

```
   try
        {

            DataSet dsCountry = objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToACountry();
            ddlCountry.DataSource = dsCountry.Tables["ACountry"];
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
            ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select Country", ""));
        }
```